# Add text to QTextEdit using QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Just a simple program to add text to textedit when button is clicked...
anything wrong here??

```
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QApplication>
#include<QTextEdit>
#include<QWidget>
#include<QHBoxLayout>
#include<QLabel>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc,argv);
QHBoxLayout *layout=new QHBoxLayout;
QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit(); 
QWidget window;
QPushButton *button;

layout->addWidget(text);
button = new QPushButton();
button->setText(QChar(i+48));

QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),text,SLOT(setPlainText("hai")));

layout->addWidget(button);
window.setLayout(layout);
window.resize(500, 500);
window.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `connect` like that. You cannot pass parameters to the `SLOT` that are not present in the connected `SIGNAL`.

You will need to connect the `clicked()` signal to your own slot (with no argument), and call the `setPlainText` function yourself (or emit a new signal that has a `QString` parameter).

The other option is to use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html), as described in the [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html#advanced-signals-and-slots-usage) advanced usage section.

Comment: you'll need either to create a real class (derived from QObject or a widget) to handle your custom slot, or read the docs I pointed out for the QSignalMapper approach. All that is well described in the Qt documentation, examples and tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, signal mapper worked out!!! But it says its aslower code, tell me if you have any other method to implement it

Comment: don't worry about slower code for signals/slots. with signal mapper you're probably just adding a few function calls-worth of overhead. unless you've got a huge mapping and hundreds of signals/second, you won't notice a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that won't work, you cannot give a slot a default argument inside the `connect` statement. The `SLOT` macros actually just transforms its argument into a string and searches for the slots name in a list of registered slots for the `text` class.

You have to call your own slot that takes no arguments and calls `setPlainText` manually with the intended text. Perhaps Qt has some helper class in that direction, but your solution should not work.

By the way, have you actually tried this and got an error, or have you just posted it here without simply trying it out?

Comment: When using slider and a lineedit, ,where any change in any one of the object reflects the other, i directly used valueChanged() in signal to setValue() in slot. if that works , why not this, can you explain me in brief if possible???

Comment: I tried and made the make file and ran it. When clicking nothing happened. And i just started using Qt just today.... just a beginner....

Comment: @user767060 Because you transmitted a value from the `valueChanged()` signal to the `setValue()` slot. But this time you ask a non-argument signal to transmit a default argument to the slot, that just doesn't work. You can drop arguments from signals in the connect method, so that a signal's argument is discarded when the slot is called, but you cannot just magically generate default arguments. The only way to do it, would be to declare the slot (in the class definition) to take a default argument, but as you change QTextEdit's code, that won't work here. See Qt's signal/slot doc for more info

Comment: @user767060 If you are such a beginner, I would suggest to read some introductory material on Qt's basics. Otherwise you made a good choice with Qt.

Comment: @user767060 The reason it worked and nothing happened is, that a wrong connect call is often not a compiler error but only a small runtime error, that is ignored by Qt (it should print an error to stdout), so that the signal is just not connected to the slot.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal and slot are incompatible. Qt provides doc for this .

Try to visit this [page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html) .

In this it says ,
  "The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.) Since the signatures are compatible, the compiler can help us detect type mismatches. Signals and slots are loosely coupled: A class which emits a signal neither knows nor cares which slots receive the signal. "

Signal slot mechanism can be compared with (or boiled down to) function call. You are calling a function(slot) in a place where signal is emitted. Now imagine that the function  expects some arguments and there is no default value. But you are trying to call the function. What will happen?. That's what happening in your code.